# Sift out dubbels

Tags: unique, records

Dear Sir/Mam iam trying to sort duplicates from a table.
I want to check if a name has teh same streetname and then only show the first result of those, resulting in unique names ommitting the doubles.
I tried the distinct(name) and the group by statements but to no avail.
Group by ended up limmiting my results

```
$klantquery = "SELECT name, ID, street, tel, email FROM  customers where name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

This query works but shows all records i need to sift out the extra ones? in order to show only unique results.

iam using mysql and php
So now i used this query:

$klantquery = "SELECT DISTINCT naam,straat,email,huisnummer,plaats,date FROM ".$GLOBALS["klanten"]." where naam LIKE '%$klantsearch%' ORDER BY naam ASC";

Works like a charm but it omits the ID row in the results so its useless??
How do include the ID field in the results?
Where is the logic?

Comment: We need to know what database you are using so we know what features can be used (e.g., TOP) We also need to know which address should be selected when there is more than one.

Comment: php and mysql and the first occurance of the name and adress combination with a preferance for first a date field and after that the ID i guess

Answer (score 0):

Got it first i selected the records i needed with distinct then later added the IDs with a subquery, elegant not realy, works though.

```
$klantquery = "SELECT Distinct naam,straat,email,huisnummer,plaats,date FROM ".$GLOBALS["klanten"]." where naam LIKE '%$klantsearch%' ORDER BY naam ASC";                

while ($result=$klantpaging->result_assoc()) {

  $subquery = "SELECT ID,naam,straat FROM ".$GLOBALS["klanten"]." where naam='".addslashes($result['naam'])."' AND straat='".$result['straat']."'"; 
  $subresult = mysql_query($subquery) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
  while ($subline = mysql_fetch_assoc($subresult)) {  
    $result[ID] = $subline[ID];
  }
  $klantrecords[] = $result;
}
```